# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid

I get the exception - **"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'"**  when I move below block from maincontent of content page to header section of master page.

```
<link href="../Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/jquery.jqGrid/jquery-ui-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

It only works when I place this block in trailing section of master page. 
Could someone help me understand why it works only when I place this block in trailing section of master page but not in header section?
I think this has something to do with loading dependencies and initialization of jqGrid, however I need concrete understanding.

Comment: Is your `jqGrid` call within `jQuery`s `document.ready` function? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: where is trailing section of master page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wait until `DOM finishes loading`. Then you can apply your scripts. Since, in your master page, you are using the script at the bottom, since the parser uses **top down** approach, it executes the script, after the body is completed loading.

So, if you do want to put in head section, ensure that all your script is inside `document.ready()` function

Also , know that it is always a **best practice** to put all your scripts at `bottom` rather than at the `header`.

This is a **good performance indicator**. Also it `avoids` the usage of `ready` function

Hope this helps..