# Scripting Error in WPF Application When using Browser Function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am Developed a Desktop application in Visual Basic 2008 for displaying website.

I used below XAML Code for my application

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" WindowState="Maximized" Width="975" Height="310">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,10,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Source="http://xxxx.com/"
            Name="MainBrowser"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When running this application, it show scripting error ("An error has occurred in this script on page").  I think it asking permission to run script. I changed security settings in IE. But no luck. Because of this error, the website not displaying properly. Please help me to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, would be even better to crop screenshot to window only.

Comment: Updated Screenshot

Comment: you may try using Webbrowser inside WindowsFormHost ?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298255/how-do-i-suppress-script-errors-when-using-the-wpf-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of searching, i founded the solution.

The solution is,

1. The Script file (.js) should be at bottom of the html file
2. Add meta query to support in IE

The query is     `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Helped post: [JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447949/javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-jqgrid)